# log4j rollingfileappender file missing

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender

We're seeing an odd problem with the RollingFileAppender.At the end of the day sometimes we look at the directory where the log files are stored, and it appears that
some of the log file numbers are missing.  It isn't just that it wrote
it out with the wrong name, that content is really missing.  The gaps in
log entry times indicate those missing file names would have contained
the missing content.

Is there anything that could explain this?  Is there something we can do
to mitigate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem was reported for DailyRollingFileAppender [here](http://vivekagarwal.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/missing-log4j-log-files-with-dailyrollingfileappender-when-they-should-roll-over/). It seems that when there's some error where log4j cannot rename a file, it simply overwrites it.